# SSRS sub-report PPT export

Tags: powerpoint, ssrs-2016

I have created a SSRS report with multiple nested sub reports as it iterates through data in each sub-report.  Upon exporting to PowerPoint the only editable data is the from the first or ‘main’ report and all of the information from the sub-reports is not editable in PowerPoint and appears as an image. I am wondering if this is a limitation of sub reports or if there is a way to get around this?  Thank you